# Attempting To Hook A Window's Window Procedure. SetWindowsHookEx Fails Return NULL HHOOK And GetLastError Returns Error Code 126

Tags: c++, winapi, setwindowshookex

### Summary

I am creating a simple application that allows the user to select a process that contains a top-level window. The user first types the path of a native DLL (not a managed DLL). Then the user types the name of the method that will be called inside the hook procedure. The method must not return a value and must be parameter-less. Then their is a button that does the hooking.

## The Problem

I am able to retrieve the module handle of the library that does the hooking. In addition, I am also able to get the module handle library the user wants to use that contains the method that he/she wants to hook. Plus, I am able to receive the procedures address both the method that user wants to hook and etc.

*In other words their is not on invalid handle being returned. Other than the handle to the hook (HHOOK)*

But SetWindowsHookEx returns a NULL HHOOK and GetLastError returns error code 126 (ERROR_NO_MOD_FOUND).

## Possible Theories On Why I Get ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND

- There is a limitation on the number of global hooks because I read somewhere with someone who has had that same error when hooking.
- I am not getting the correct module handle of the DLL that will do the hooking. But then again I have tried many different method to get the libraries HMODULE/HINSTANCE but all fail with the same error.

## WinHooker.cpp

```
#include "winhooker.h"
HMODULE GetCurrentModule()
{ 
  HMODULE hModule = NULL;
  GetModuleHandleEx(
    GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
    (LPCTSTR)GetCurrentModule,
    &hModule);

  return hModule;
}
LRESULT (WINAPI hookProc)(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void recievedCallback(WIN32Hooker* hooker);
WIN32Hooker* current;

            WIN32Hooker::WIN32Hooker(HINSTANCE* hInstance, Callback callback)
            {
                if (!hInstance)
                {
                    HMODULE hModule = GetCurrentModule();
                    hInstance = &hModule;
                }
                this->callback = callback;
                this->hInstance = hInstance;
                return;
            }
            void WIN32Hooker::Hook(DWORD threadToHook)
            {
                recievedCallback(this);
                this->hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, hookProc, *this->hInstance, threadToHook);
                DWORD errorCode = GetLastError(); // 126 ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND
                return;
            }
            void WIN32Hooker::NextHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
            {
                callback();
                CallNextHookEx(this->hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
                return;
            }
            void WIN32Hooker::Free()
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(this->hhk);
                return;
            }



LRESULT (WINAPI hookProc)(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    current->NextHook(nCode, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}
void recievedCallback(WIN32Hooker* hooker)
{
    current = hooker;
}
extern "C" WIN32Hooker* hookerMalloc(HINSTANCE* hInstance, Callback callback)
{
    return new WIN32Hooker(hInstance, callback);
}
```

## Test.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
extern "C" void sendMessage(void)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Test", L"Test", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

## Main Code

```
// Window Hooker Bytes.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Window Hooker Bytes.h"
#include "processes.h"
#include "button.h"
#include "edit.h"
#include "listbox.h"
#include "/Users/FatalisProgrammer/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Window Hooker Bytes/WindowHookerLib/winhooker.h"
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
using namespace Processes;
using namespace Controls;
void Delete(); // Delete proto-type
void windowListCallback(map<HWND, wstring>* list); // Callback proto-type
// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
Button* hookButton;
Edit* dllPathEdit;
Edit* methodNameEdit;
ListBox* windowList;
ProcessEnumerator* processEnumerator;
map<HWND, wstring> mapList;
// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWHOOKERBYTES, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {

        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWHOOKERBYTES));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWHOOKERBYTES));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWHOOKERBYTES);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 800 / 2, 480 / 2, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
   hookButton = new Button(hWnd, 120, L"Hook Method From DLL!", 5, (480 / 2) - 24 - 24 - 24 - 6, (800 / 2) - 15, 24);
   hookButton->show(hInst);
   dllPathEdit = new Edit(hWnd, 169, 5, 5, (800 / 2) - 15, 24);
   dllPathEdit->show(hInst);
   dllPathEdit->setWatermarkText(L"Enter Path Of A Native DLL.");
   methodNameEdit = new Edit(hWnd, 256, 5, (5 * 2) + 24, (800 / 2) - 15, 24);
   methodNameEdit->show(hInst);
   methodNameEdit->setWatermarkText(L"Enter Method (Must Return Void And Be Parameterless)");
   methodNameEdit->setFont(L"Times", 16);
   dllPathEdit->setFont(L"Times", 16);
   hookButton->setFont(L"Times", 16);
   windowList = new ListBox(hWnd, 333, 5, (5 * 8) + 24, (800 / 2) - 15, (124 / 2) + 24);
   windowList->show(hInst);
   windowList->setFont(L"Times", 16);
   hookButton->setUACShield();
   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }
   processEnumerator = new ProcessEnumerator();
   processEnumerator->enumerateProcesses(windowListCallback);
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

        if (wmId == hookButton->getID())
        {
            HMODULE libraryModule = LoadLibrary(L"WindowHookerLib.dll");
            typedef WIN32Hooker* (*HookerMalloc)(HINSTANCE* hInstance, Callback callback);
            HookerMalloc hookerMalloc =  (HookerMalloc)GetProcAddress(libraryModule, "hookerMalloc");
            DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
            HMODULE libraryToHookModule = LoadLibrary(dllPathEdit->getText());
            if (!libraryToHookModule || !libraryModule)
            {
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Error: Library That Contains The Method To Hook Or The WindowHookerLib.dll Does Not Exist!\nMake Sure WindowHookerLib.dll Is In The Current Working Directory!", L"Error In Application!", MB_ICONERROR);
            }
            else
            {
                typedef void (__stdcall *Method)(void);
                char* methodName = new char[wcslen(methodNameEdit->getText()) * 2];
                wcstombs(methodName, methodNameEdit->getText(), wcslen(methodNameEdit->getText()) * 2);
                Method method = (Method)GetProcAddress(libraryToHookModule, methodName);
                if (!hookerMalloc || !method)
                {
                    MessageBox(hWnd, L"Error: The Method To Hook Does Not Exist Or The Method To Initiate The Hooker Is Not Available!", L"Error In Application", MB_ICONERROR);
                }
                else
                {
                    WIN32Hooker* hooker = hookerMalloc(NULL, method);
                    DWORD pID;
                    int selectedItemIndex = windowList->getSelectedIndex();
                    vector<HWND> v;
                    for(map<HWND,wstring>::iterator it = mapList.begin(); it != mapList.end(); ++it) 
                    {
                        v.push_back(it->first);
                    }
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(v[selectedItemIndex], &pID);
                    if (pID >= 0)
                    {

                        hooker->Hook(pID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox(hWnd, L"Error Could Not Retrieve Process ID!", L"Error In Application", MB_ICONERROR);
                    }

                }
                delete methodName;
            }
        }

        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {

        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        Delete();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

void Delete()
{
    delete dllPathEdit;
    delete hookButton;
    delete methodNameEdit;
    delete windowList;
    processEnumerator->free();
    delete processEnumerator;
    return;
}
void windowListCallback(map<HWND, wstring>* list)
{
    mapList = *list;
    vector<wstring> v;
    for(map<HWND,wstring>::iterator it = mapList.begin(); it != mapList.end(); ++it) 
    {
        v.push_back(it->second);
    }
    for each(wstring item in v)
    {
        windowList->addItem(item);
    }
    return;
}
```

## Conclusion

Any help would be appreciated. If I am doing something wrong, feel free to point it out. This project is for learning purposes, so tell me what needs to be fixed, or any tips would be great.

Comment: Your pointer code is borken, you set hInstance to the address of a local variable.  Fix: `hInstance = (HINSTANCE)hModule;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code:

```
HMODULE hModule = GetCurrentModule();
hInstance = &hModule;
```

you are assigning the address of a local variable to `hInstance`.  When this is dereferenced in the call to `SetWindowsHookEx` you'll get a bogus value.

Throughout the code, don't use a pointer to an `HINSTANCE`, just use a plain `HINSTANCE`.

Comment: Thanks For The Help. It Solved That Problem.